# Free personal push notifications service

Tags: gratis, api, notification

I'm looking for a free service that allows me to send push notifications/messages to my phone using a simple API call.

The use case: I have found for some of my personal projects, that I want to know when something happens in/on them instantly. It would be useful to send a message to my phone so I know, in real-time, when a certain action is performed (e.g. a mobile app just had an in app purchase and my server has been notified -- I'd like to know about this on my phone straight away too!)

I used to use Twilio to send myself an SMS from the server (actually just a Firebase Cloud Function) but that has a cost per message (albeit quite low!). I'm looking for a service that would allow me to achieve the same thing for free, and it doesn't have to be by SMS -- an app that comes with the service that responds to my messages and pushes them to my device would be perfect too.

Note that I'm only really interested in sending messages to *myself*, essentially just an email to myself but I was curious to see whether there is a service out there that wraps the entire process from sending to delivery itself!

A quick list of my requirements:

- Service that has an API for me to send messages to, which it then delivers to my phone (in any way, e.g. SMS or using an Internet connection)
- The message should be readable on my phone which is running Android (8.0)
- The service should be free (I don't mind if it's only free for the first x messages per e.g. month, but then costs more if I need to send more, or other similar constraints)
- I currently just want to send plain text messages, but if it supported sending images/other media that would be a bonus (this feature could be paid)

Comment: What about Pushover? Cost for the device but then you get free notifications.

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName I hadn't heard of pushover, thanks! it seems to be a one-off $5 per platform fee, which doesn't seem too bad, but I'll wait to see if any other answers come up with something that has a free basic 'tier' but please feel free to post an answer as it may help others!